# Match the items in column in one dataframe and replace with the corresponding item from another dataframe

Tags: regex, r

I have dataframe `mydf` with two columns `LeftGenes` and `RightGenes`. I have another dataframe `mydf2` . I want to match item in mydf columns (if multiple, they are separated by ':') with the accession column in mydf2 and replace with the corresponding gene_id and get the result.

```
mydf <-structure(c("NP_570602", "NA", "NA", "XP_006719119:NR_040112", 
"NA", "NA", "NM_000662:NM_001160170:NM_001160171", "NA"), .Dim = c(4L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("LeftGenes", "RightGenes")))

mydf2<-structure(list(gene_id = c("1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", 
    "9", "9", "9"), accession = c("NM_130786", "NP_570602", "NM_000014", 
    "NP_000005", "XM_006719056", "XP_006719119", "NR_040112", "NM_000662", 
    "NM_001160170", "NM_001160171")), .Names = c("gene_id", "accession"
    ), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

result

```
  LeftGenes      RightGenes
1   1               NA
2   NA              NA
3   NA              9:9:9
4   2:3             NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
mydf <- data.frame(mydf)

#we use this to split up each LeftGene and RightGene to get all the available options
tmpleft <- strsplit(as.character(mydf$LeftGenes),":")
tmpright <- strsplit(as.character(mydf$RightGenes),":")


# here are your desired "left" results in a list
leftres <- lapply(1:length(tmpleft), 
              function(m) paste(mydf2$gene_id[match(tmpleft[[m]],mydf2$accession)],collapse=":"))

# here are your desired "right" results in a list
rightres <- lapply(1:length(tmpright), 
                   function(m) paste(mydf2$gene_id[match(tmpright[[m]],mydf2$accession)],collapse=":"))

# now we just need to join them into a dataframe
res <- data.frame(t(data.frame(leftres)),t(data.frame(rightres)))
colnames(res) <- c("LeftGenes","RightGenes")
rownames(res) <- 1:length(tmpleft)
```